# Enable html in joomla editor

Tags: joomla, editor, joomla2.5

In one of my joomla custom form, I am rendering an editor as follows

```
<?php
        $qu=$question ? $question : '';
        $editor = JFactory::getEditor();
        echo $editor->display('question', $qu, '100%', '400', '80', '15');
?>
```

The editor was working fine But when I am trying to submit after formatting, its html part won't get sumitted. If the editor was loading from xml `filter="safehtml" or filter="raw"` will work. But how to enable html in this case ?

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in  `JRequest::GET` which by default strips all html.

You have to ask specifically the input you want html from.

```
JRequest::getVar( 'yourfieldname', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML );
```

[Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor)